# not getting response in success function of ajax

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, codeigniter

hello i want to display data of business2's data according to business1's dropdown list but on change() of business1 i got data in response but how to print it in second dropdown list using id. i didn't get response in success function. How to print options of dropdown list using Id. 
I got response in mozila's firefox's console but i don't know how to return it in success and then how to print in second dropdown list.

```
<!-- ajax code starts here -->

            <script>
                    $(document).on('change', 'select.Business1', function(){
                           var business1 = $('select.Business1 option:selected').val();
                           alert(business1);
                           var value = $(this).val();

                           $.ajax({
                                type:"POST",
                                data: { business1:business1 },
                                url: '<?php echo site_url('client_area/select_business_sub_cat'); ?>',
                                sucess : function (data){
                                        alert(1);
                                        var abc = $('#business2').html(data);
                                }
                           });
                    });
            </script>


<!-- ajax code ends here -->
```

Model function

```
public function select_business_sub_cat()
    {
        $business1 = $this->input->post('business1');
        $result_sub_cat1 = $this->db->query("select category.id,subcategory.* From category LEFT JOIN subcategory ON category.id = subcategory.category_id where category.id = '$business1'");
        $row_cat1 = $result_sub_cat1->result();

        $data = array(
            'id' => $row_cat1['0']->id,
            'name' => $row_cat1['0']->name
            );
        echo "<option value='" . $row_cat1['0']->id . "'>" . $row_cat1['0']->name . "</option>"; 
        // return $this->output->set_output($data);  
    }
```

View  --

```
<div class="form-group">
                                <label>Business 1</label>
                                <select name="txtBusiness1" id="" style="height: 30px;width: 100%;" class="Business1">
                                                 <option value=""> Select Business </option>
                                                 <?php 
                                                 $result_cat1 =  $this->db->query("select * from category");
                                                 $row_cat1 = $result_cat1->result();
                                                 ?>
                                                <?php foreach($row_cat1 as $item){ ?>
                                                <option value="<?php echo $item->id; ?>"><?php echo $item->name; ?></option>
                                                <?php } ?>
                                </select>                        
                         </div>
                         <div class="form-group">
                                <label>Business 2</label>
                                <select name="txtBusiness2" id="business2" style="height: 30px;width: 100%;" class="Business2">
                                                 <option value=""> Select Business2 </option>

                                </select>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

2 things may creating issue:

1) add double quotes in url

2) make it success instead of sucess

```
$.ajax({
     type:"POST",
     data: { business1:business1 },
     url: '<?php echo site_url("client_area/select_business_sub_cat"); ?>', // add double quotes in url
     success : function (data){ // make it success instead of sucess
              alert(1);
              var abc = $('#business2').html(data);
              }
});
```

Comment: ohk thank you brother ... I got alert(1) now and  i got response in mozila like <option value='2'>Sub_cat1</option> now to i want to echo it in dropdown with id business2 . but error is ReferenceError: data is not defined.

Comment: try to alert data instead of 1...what is coming then?

Comment: brother I got blank in alert.

Comment: it was my fault there is a missing '<' in my response so alert was blank.. thank you so..much brother for quick solutions.

Answer (score 3):

You have a type in your ajax call:

```
success : function (data) {
```

It's `success` not `sucess`

Comment: oh great thank you brother for the quick response..  now i got alert(1); but i want to print options in business2 label with id of business2 . i got response in mozila like <option value='2'>Sub_cat1</option> but with error but error is ReferenceError: data is not defined.

Answer (score 1):

Change sucesss to success. You are using CI framework then use CI parameterized query, don't use static query it's hackable.
Give unique id to both div and select

It's better to follow MVC if you are use CI. Put your query in model with ci parameterized query.

```
         <div class="form-group" id = 'divtxtBusiness1'>
                            <label>Business 1</label>
                            <select name="txtBusiness1" id="txtBusiness1" style="height: 30px;width: 100%;" class="Business1">
                                ........         
                            </select>                        
                     </div>

                     <div class="form-group" id = "div_Business_2">
                            <label>Business 2</label>
                            <select name="txtBusiness2" id="business2" style="height: 30px;width: 100%;" class="Business2">
                                             <option value=""> Select Business2 </option>

                            </select> 
                    </div>
```

```
        <script>
                //$(document).on('change', 'select.Business1', function(){
                 //      var business1 = $('select.Business1 option:selected').val();
                $(document).on('change', '#txtBusiness1', function(){
                       var business1 = $('#txtBusiness1').val();
                       //alert(business1);
                       //var value = $(this).val();

                       $.ajax({
                            type:"POST",
                            data: { business1:business1 },
                            url: '<?php echo site_url("client_area/select_business_sub_cat"); ?>',
                            success : function (data){
                                    //alert(1);
                                    $('#div_Business_2 #business2').remove();
                                    $('#div_Business_2').append(data);
                            }
                       });
                });
        </script>
```

Controller :

```
public function select_business_sub_cat()
{
    $business1 = $this->input->post('business1');
    $result_sub_cat1 = $this->xyzmodel->xyzmodelfunction($business1)
    $str = '<select name="txtBusiness2" id="business2" style="height: 30px;width: 100%;" class="Business2">';
    for($i = 0 ; $i< count($result_sub_cat1) ; $i++)
    {
           $str .= '<option value="'.$result_sub_cat1['id'].'"> '.$result_sub_cat1['name'].' </option>';
    }

     $str .= '</select>';
     echo $str;                        
    // return $this->output->set_output($data);  
}
```

Model :
don't use static query it's hackable.

```
class Xyzmodel extends CI_Model
{

    ...... 
    public function xyzmodelfunction($business1)
    {
        $this->db->select(category.id,subcategory.*);
        $this->db->from('category');
        $this->db->join("subcategory", "category.id = subcategory.category_id", 'LEFT');
        $this->db->where('category.id', $business1);
        $result = $this->db->get();
        return $result->result_array();
    }
    ........
}
```